# Values changing when passing from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a bit of a problem with a thing. I put some bool values in the ViewBag, but when they reach the View they change their values. I have this in my controller action

```
        var buckets = db.Buckets.ToList();
        int i=0;
        ViewBag.CV = new bool[buckets.Count];

        foreach (Bucket b in buckets)
        {
            var payByInvoice = db.PaymentOptions.Where(p => p.BucketId == b.Id).Select(p => p.CanPayByInvoice).SingleOrDefault();
            if (payByInvoice != (int)PayByInvoiceState.Accepted)
            {
                ViewBag.CV[i] = false;
            }
            if (payByInvoice == (int)PayByInvoiceState.Accepted)
            { 
                ViewBag.CV[i] = true;
            }
                i++;
        }
```

When the `foreach` finishes his job, the values that are retained in `ViewBag.CV` are as follows:

`ViewBag.CV[0] = true;`
`ViewBag.CV[1] = false;`
`ViewBag.CV[2] = false;`

When the values hit the View they all change to `false`. I don't know why, but it sets all the values with the evaluation of the first `if`. If I change the `true` on the first `if` and `false` on the 2nd, I get only `true` when the values reach the View.

Any ideas would be most welcomed.

Comment: Why are you using ViewBag? Just use a view model.

Comment: It's not about what I use, it's about the behavior of this thing. And I would like to know why is this happening, or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Well, you know, ViewBag/ViewCrap :-) Since I have stopped using it, I don't have any problems. You could of course feel free to continue using it. Good luck.

Comment: If you need a `for` loop, just use one.

Comment: Well OK, I could change this. But I need a solution to this, not an alternative... So if you have any ideas on why this is happening, please share.

Comment: No, sorry, I have absolutely no idea. Hopefully someone will have.

Comment: @DavinTryon Why would I need a `for` ? The problem isn't inside the `foreach`, the problem is that when I list the values of `ViewBag.CV` they are all messed up.

Comment: That is why I left a comment and not an answer.  You are initializing an `i` to `0`, incrementing by `1` each loop, and then using the `i` to index into the a collection.  Just seems it would be cleaner to use a `for`.

Comment: Probably values are taken from modelstate. if you clear modelstate before rendering view. this problem should dissapear, but it might add some new problems

Comment: I found the problem in the View. I was using a faulty piece of code (incremented the index for the ViewBag.CV in a point that was making a single loop), so actually the ViewBag was OK, problem was how I used it in the View. Thanks for all your replies.